# Filter projection of SELECT statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I project several columns using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute")"gendata"."Employee Name","gendata"."Position", "gendata"."Department",  "TrainingMatrix".* "
            "FROM "TrainingMatrix" "
            "JOIN "gendata" ON "TrainingMatrix".payroll = "gendata".payroll "
            "ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST
```

I would like to filter the result based on`"TrainingMatrix".payroll` value. I tried the following but it show me error:

```
SELECT *  (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute")"gendata"."Employee Name","gendata"."Position", "gendata"."Department",  "TrainingMatrix".* "
            "FROM "TrainingMatrix" "
            "JOIN "gendata" ON "TrainingMatrix".payroll = "gendata".payroll "
            "ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST) WEHRE "TrainingMatrix".payroll='40612010' ;"
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "("
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

***Edit:***

```
SELECT * from  (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute")"gendata"."Employee Name","gendata"."Position", "gendata"."Department",  "TrainingMatrix".* 

           FROM "TrainingMatrix" 
           JOIN "gendata" ON "TrainingMatrix".payroll = "gendata".payroll 
           ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST) where "TrainingMatrix".payroll='40612010' ;
```

Now I got:

> ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias LINE 1: SELECT * from 
>   (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll...

Comment: Shows you what error?

Comment: you frogot the `FROM` in your statement

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but since that's not a computed column or anything, can't it just go in a normal WHERE clause, without the sub-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a from for your subquery and you missspelled WHERE.

Edit: And add alias

```
SELECT * from (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute")"gendata"."Employee Name","gendata"."Position", "gendata"."Department",  "TrainingMatrix".* "
         ^^^^
            "FROM "TrainingMatrix" "
            "JOIN "gendata" ON "TrainingMatrix".payroll = "gendata".payroll "
            "ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST) a where "TrainingMatrix".payroll='40612010' ;"
                                                                                             ^ ^^^^^
```

Comment: @Aan: well, add an alias (after the `)`)

Comment: @wildplasser: how to do that, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I can help.: find the `)` and put an alias after it, like in: `s/NULLS LAST) where /NULLS LAST) omg where /`